# how to bind array value from api to "react-select" component option value in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I've try this but not worked

```
{Members.map(Members=>
<Select
className="effect-16"
dataSource={Members.displayName}
placeholder="Select Section"
value={this.state.selectedOptions}
OnChange = {this.handleSelect}
isSearchable = {true}
isMulti
isClearable
/>
)}
```

Output display like following image

[image: [enter image description here]()]

Give me solution for this

Comment: `<Select ... dataSource={Members.map(m => m.displayName)}` /> something like that?

Comment: I've tried this too but not worked as well. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For binding Array values to react-select options, you need to pass an array of objects with **label and value pair**.

Like this:

```
const arr = [{ key: "test 1", value: 1 }, { key: "test 2", value: 2 }];

<Select
  options={arr}
  ...
/>
```

Please take this as an example, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For this issue, I found a solution for using Multiselect component:

```
import Multiselect from 'multiselect-react-dropdown';

    
    this.state = {  PersonName: []  }
    
     GetValues = async () => {
            let url = "someapi link";
            let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
            const accessToken = user;
            const reqData = await fetch(url, {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken,
                    "Content-type": "application/json",
                    "Accept": "application/json",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Access-Control-Request-Headers "
                },
            })

            const resData = await reqData.json();

            for (let i = 0; i < resData.length; i++) 
            {
                this.state.PersonName.push(resData[i].label);
            }

            this.setState({ PersonName: this.state.PersonName })
    }
    
    
    <Multiselect className="effect-16" showArrow
    options={PersonName}
    getSelectedItems={PersonName}
    isObject={false} />
```

Comment: Video source : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OtEqBBcPREY